# Handling common recursive functions

Tags: c#, recursion, hierarchy

I've noticed that in my project, we frequently are writing recursive functions.

My question is: is there any way to create the recursive function as generic function for each hierarchy structure that is using the recursive iteration?

Maybe I can use a delegate that gets the root and the end flag of the recursion?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You are going to need to be more specific.  There may be a way to make it generic, but we cannot help without more information.

Comment: A code sample of what you are looking to genericise would be a great help here.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a way to work with hierarchical structures in a generic way ("generic" as defined in English, not necessarily as defined in .Net). For example, this is something I wrote once when I needed to get all the Controls inside a Windows Form:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectManyRecursive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
{
    if (items == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
    if (selector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");

    return SelectManyRecursiveInternal(items, selector);
}

private static IEnumerable<T> SelectManyRecursiveInternal<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
{
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        yield return item;
        IEnumerable<T> subitems = selector(item);

        if (subitems != null)
        {
            foreach (T subitem in subitems.SelectManyRecursive(selector))
                yield return subitem;
        }
    }
}


// sample use, get Text from some TextBoxes in the form
var strings = form.Controls
                  .SelectManyRecursive(c => c.Controls) // all controls
                  .OfType<TextBox>() // filter by type
                  .Where(c => c.Text.StartWith("P")) // filter by text
                  .Select(c => c.Text);
```

Another example: a `Category` class where each `Category` could have `ChildCategories` (same way a `Control` has a `Controls` collection) and assuming that `rootCategory` is directly or indirectly the parent of all categories:

```
// get all categories that are enabled
var categories = from c in rootCategory.SelectManyRecursive(c => c.ChildCategories)
                 where c.Enabled
                 select c;
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: is there any way to create the recursive function as generic function for each hierarchy structure that is using the recusive iteration?
>   may be i can use a delegate that gets the root and the end flag of the recursive?

Yes - The only thing you need is a delegate function that computes a list of children for each element. The function terminates when no children are returned.

```
    delegate IEnumerable<TNode> ChildSelector<TNode>(TNode Root);

    static IEnumerable<TNode> Traverse<TNode>(this TNode Root, ChildSelector<TNode> Children) {
        // Visit current node (PreOrder)
        yield return Root;

        // Visit children
        foreach (var Child in Children(Root)) 
            foreach (var el in Traverse(Child, Children))
                yield return el;

    }
```

Example:

```
        static void Main(string[] args) {

        var Init = // Some path

        var Data = Init.Traverse(Dir => Directory.GetDirectories(Dir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));

        foreach (var Dir in Data)
            Console.WriteLine(Dir);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: +1 The delegate declaration is required for .Net 2.0. If you are targeting .Net 3.5+, however, you can simply use Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly your question is asking for but a recursive function can be generic. There's no limitation on that. For instance:

```
int CountLinkedListNodes<T>(MyLinkedList<T> input) {
   if (input == null) return 0;
   return 1 + CountLinkedListNodes<T>(input.Next);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier and also generic approach might be to cache the results of the function and use the "real" function only when the result is known - the effectivness of this approach depends how frequently the same set of parameters is used during your recursion.

If you know Perl you should check the first 4 chapters of [Higher-Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/) which are available as a EBook, the ideas presented are language-independent.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your solution can successfully use the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

You can create a specific variation of the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) by creating a [hierarchical visitor pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HierarchicalVisitorPattern).

It is a little complex to discuss entirely here, but that should get you started into some research.  The basic idea is that you have a class that knows how to traverse the structure, and then you have Visitor classes that know how to process a particular node.  You can separate the traversal of the tree with the processing of nodes.